# Multiple android-menudrawer in same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, drawer

I am curreny using the menudrawer from https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer.

When i try to display the menu from the top & bottom, with the apropiate gestures, i get only one response. Do you know if there can be used more than 1 menus in the same activity?

```
    mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.TOP);
    mMenuDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN);
    mMenuDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMenuDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.mt_main);

    mMenuDrawer2 = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.BOTTOM);
    mMenuDrawer2.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN);
    mMenuDrawer2.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMenuDrawer2.setMenuView(R.layout.mb_main);
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? Is it possible to have two sliding drawers for one layout using MenuDrawer?

Answer (score 1):

I use two menudrawers in my activity and I use them as follow (and its working for me)

```
mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.TOP);
        mMenuDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN);
        mMenuDrawer.setDropShadowEnabled(false);

mMenuDrawerRight = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT, Position.RIGHT);
        mMenuDrawerRight.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL );
        mMenuDrawerRight.setTouchBezelSize(10);
        mMenuDrawerRight.setDropShadowEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I've tried something like this but can't get it working, sure I'm missing something obvious; how did you set menuDrawers contentViews?

Answer (score 0):

If the library supports such a thing `MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN` won't help at all... try with `MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL`

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, MenuDrawer didn't officially support multiple drawers without possibly using some kind of hack. [SlidngMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) does support adding multiple drawers, wherever you want. I think MenuDrawer performs better, but SlidingMenu gives you more options and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to attach two `MenuDrawer` (on left and right) to same activity

Default mode for MenuDrawer is `MENU_DRAG_CONTENT` but we need to use `MENU_DRAG_WINDOW`

**Note: Don't set the ContentView for MenuDrawers**

```
//In onCreate() of the activity
MenuDrawer slidingMenuLeft = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.Type.OVERLAY, Position.LEFT, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_WINDOW);
slidingMenuLeft.setMenuView(R.layout.navigation_menu_left); // Set layout for Left menu

MenuDrawer slidingMenuRight = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.Type.OVERLAY, Position.RIGHT, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_WINDOW);
slidingMenuRight.setMenuView(R.layout.navigation_menu_right);  // Set layout for Right menu
```

I haven't tested this with touch mode `MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN`